# Precompiling additional assets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I've been converting a project to use the asset pipeline, but am hitting a wall with one part of the deployment. I have getting the below error after a cap deploy to a production server. (Everything work's ok in development mode without the precompilation of assets)

```
simile-ajax-api.js isn't precompiled
```

the project structure is something like

```
|-app/
  |-assets/
    |-javascripts/
      |- application.js
|-vendor/
  |-assets/
    |-javascripts/
    |-timeline/
      |-timeline_ajax/
        |-simile-ajax-api.js
```

In my application.rb I have added the following line

```
config.assets.paths << "vendor/assets/timeline/timeline_ajax"
```

and in my production.rb, I have added

```
  precompile_list = %w(app lib vendor).map do |path|
    Dir[Rails.root.join(*%W(#{path} assets ** *))].select do |f|
      f =~ /(\.js|\.s?css)/
    end
  end.flatten.map do |f|
    f.split(File::SEPARATOR).last
  end.uniq
config.assets.precompile = (config.assets.precompile + precompile_list).uniq
config.assets.precompile << Rails.root.join(*%w( vendor assets timeline timeline_ajax simile-ajax-api.js ))
```

The application.js looks like this:

```
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require global
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/timeline/timeline_ajax/.
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/timeline/timeline_js/.
//= require timeline-api
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require FixedHeader.min
//= require ColVis.min
//= require jquery.ba-resize.min
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.blockUI
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
//= require_tree .
```

and finally, the bit where it is getting loaded in application.html.haml is

```
%html
  %head
    - page_title = @page_title ? "#{@page_title}" : ''
    %title= strip_tags page_title

    :javascript
      Timeline_ajax_url= "#{asset_path('simile-ajax-api.js')}";
      Timeline_urlPrefix= '/assets/';
      Timeline_parameters='bundle=true'
```

Any idea's where I'm going wrong? Please let me know if there are more details you need.

Comment: is typo issue ? `javascripts` is missing on path

Comment: Hi Amar - sorry for the confusion, the timeline code is deliberately outside of the javascripts directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need to state the path like this :

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/timeline/timeline_ajax/.
```

Just :

```
//= require_tree timeline/timeline_ajax/.
```

Because all the assets (no matter where are located ) are looked up the same way . Simply put - if the dir is named `assets` , the pipeline looks up for files to be included .

EDIT : As it seems your `vendor` directory structure is a little strange : normally you copy your `.js` files directly to `assets/javascripts` directory . I think including `assets/vendor/timeline` is going to make things complicated . Just copy `timeline` dir into `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the refactoring doesn't appear to have fixed it.

Comment: You can consider returning to the default settings for pipeline in the `production.rb` . In my working app (rails 3.2.8) the settings , related to the `pipeline` are just :   `# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )` . In case you try to copy your `simile-ajax-api.js` file into `vendor/assets/javascripts` , it should be OK .

Comment: Thanks Quamara, I've have a reshuffle of the structure of this project and cleaned up the production.rb and it seems to be working now!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it . Good luck.